# iterating the list in JSTL

Tags: java, jstl

I have the controller file which holds a list of values in the model like,

```
List caseIds = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0; i<caseLists.size(); i++)
{
    if(caseIds.contains(caseLists.get(i).getCaseId()))
        continue;
    else 
        caseIds.add(caseLists.get(i).getCaseId());             
}
model.put("caseIdList", caseIds);
```

and i want to show this caseIds in UI in a  dropdown box. My code looks like this,

```
<select name="caseIds" id="caseIds">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${model.caseIdList}">
        <option value="<c:out value='${item.caseIdList}'/>" >
            <c:out value="${item.caseIdList}"/>     
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

I mean I want the dropdown(select box) with an id and value as caseId's. I understand that there is an error in getting item with item.caseIdList. How should I approach?

Comment: Does `item` have a property named `caseIdList`? What type of data does `caseIds` hold?

Comment: isn't it `item.caseId` ?

Comment: caseIdList is set in the action class. And it has values like 1000, 1001...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` in the for loop in the jsp will be the caseId that was added with `caseLists.get(i).getCaseId()`, so I think you just want the following:

```
<select name="caseIds" id="caseIds">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${model.caseIdList}">
        <option value="<c:out value='${item}'/>" >
            <c:out value="${item}"/>     
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to do :

```
<select name="caseIds" id="caseIds">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${model.caseIdList}">
        <option value="<c:out value='${item}'/>" >
            <c:out value="${item}"/>     
        </option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

You need to use `item` instead of `item.caseIdList` since the `caseIdList` contains `Integer`.